# $P(X>0,Y>0)$ for a bivariate normal distribution with correlation $\rho$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ have a bivariate normal distribution with $\rho$ as covariance. $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal variables.

I showed that $X$ and $Z= \dfrac{Y-\rho X}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$ are independent standard normal variables.

Using this I need to show that

$$P(X >0,Y>0) = \frac14 + \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot\arcsin(\rho).$$

Comment: As a hint for the first question, notice that $Z$ is the conditional of $Y$ on $X$.

Comment: it is easy to solve part. As X and Y are standard normal variables. But I am stuck at part two.

Comment: If it is easy for part 1, why are you asking the question?

Comment: Because the second part is to use first part to solve second.

Comment: @user669083 Learner is right. If you want an answer for part II, then you shouldnt say: "I had to show..." You need to say "using the fact that .....", I need to show : "part II"

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36544/321264

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $\left( V, W \right)$ be i.i.d standard normal, let $U$ be uniform on
$\left[ - \pi, \pi \right)$ independent of $R = \sqrt{V^2 + W^2}$ and let
$\varphi = \arcsin \rho$. Then the following vectors have the same
distributions (think about the [Box-Muller transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform))
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \left( X, Y \right) & \overset{d}{=} & \sqrt{2} \left( V \cos \varphi + W
  \sin \varphi, W \right)\\
  \left( V, W \right) & \overset{d}{=} & R \left( \cos U, \sin U \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Implying
\begin{eqnarray*}
  P \left[ X > 0, Y > 0 \right] & = & P \left[ \cos U \cos \varphi + \sin U
  \sin \varphi > 0, \sin U > 0 \right]\\
  & = & P \left[ U \in \left( \varphi - \frac{\pi}{2}, \varphi +
  \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \cap \left( 0, \pi \right) \right]\\
  & = & \frac{\varphi}{2 \pi} + \frac{1}{4}
\end{eqnarray*}

---

**Here is an alternative proof:**

Let $\phi$ be the density of the standard normal distribution
\begin{eqnarray*}
  P \left[ X > 0, Y > 0 \right] & = & P \left[ X < 0, Y < 0 \right]\\
  & = & \int_{- \infty}^0 \phi \left( z \right) \int_{- \infty}^0
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} \phi \left( \frac{x - \rho z}{\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}}
  \right) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} z\\
  & = & \int_{- \infty}^0 \phi \left( z \right) \int_{- \infty}^{- \frac{\rho
  z}{\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}}} \phi \left( x \right) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} z
\end{eqnarray*}
Let's call the above integral $h \left( \rho \right)$, then after some
simplifications
$$\frac{\partial h \left( \rho \right)}{\partial \rho} = \frac{1}{2 \pi
   \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} $$
By integrating back (or considering the problem as a first-order ordinary differential equation), $h \left( \rho \right) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \arcsin \rho +
K$ where $K$ is some constant. By the special case of independence, $h \left( 0 \right) =
\frac{1}{4}$, you get the final solution
$$ P \left[ X > 0, Y > 0 \right] = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \arcsin \rho + \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: @user669083 If you do not understand the above proof, you should point to the part where you have problems. Anyway, I am going to add an alternative proof (I am not sure it is simpler).

Comment: Let's call the above integral h(ρ), then after some simplifications. What is your simplification? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fafsads Please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule for how to differentiate with respect to $\rho$. After that, all is needed is some simple manipulations of one-dimensional normal density integrals. Let me know after that if you are still having trouble.

Comment: I solved it by writing the equation as $(PX>0,Z> {\frac{-\rho X}{\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}}})$. After that write in terms of integral, convert into polar co-ordinates and voila I got the answer

Answer (score 8):

Using the OP's hint: The event $\{X>0,Y>0\}$ is the same as the event $\{X>0,Z>\frac{-\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}X\}$, where now $X$ and $Z$ are independent standard normal variables.  Writing $a:=\frac{-\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$ for brevity, the desired probability is expressible as a double integral involving the joint density of $(X,Z)$:
$$
P(X>0,Y>0)=P(X>0,Z>aX)=\int_{x=0}^\infty\int_{z=ax}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz\,dx.
$$
Switching to polar coordinates, this equals
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\theta=\arctan(a)}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^\infty\frac1{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2}\,rdrd\theta&=\int_{\theta=\arctan(a)}^{\pi/2}\frac1{2\pi}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan a\right)\\
&=\frac14+\frac1{2\pi}\arctan\frac\rho{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}};
\end{align}
$$
for the last equality we substitute $a:=\frac{-\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$ and use the fact that the arctan function is odd. To finish off, remember that if $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ then $$\theta=\arctan\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\ \Longleftrightarrow\ \tan\theta=\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\ \Longleftrightarrow\ \sin\theta=\rho\ \Longleftrightarrow\ \theta=\arcsin \rho.$$