# Probability that multi-dimensional random variable is positive?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If we have some multi-dimensional normal probability distribution, $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, with zero mean and a known covariance matrix  then what is the probability that every component of $X$ is greater than or equal to zero?

$$\mathbb{P}(\forall i.X_i \ge 0) = \: ?$$

Comment: If $X$ is $n$-dimensional, where $n>1$, then that probability does not make sense.

Comment: Presumably it means all components are $\ge 0$.

Comment: yes, i meant all the components. Hopefully my edit clarifies.

Comment: Some discussion related to orthant probabilities of normal distribution can be found in these books: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-9655-0, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0471722065.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stuart and Ord (1994, *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics*, volume 1, Section 15.10) report symbolic solutions for the standardised bivariate Normal orthant probability $P(X>0,Y>0)$ as:

$$\text{P2}=\frac{\sin ^{-1}(\rho )}{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{4}$$

... while the standardised trivariate Normal orthant probability $P(X>0,Y>0,Z>0)$ is:

$$\text{P3}=\frac{\sin ^{-1}\left(\rho _{\text{xy}}\right)+\sin ^{-1}\left(\rho _{\text{xz}}\right)+\sin ^{-1}\left(\rho _{\text{yz}}\right)}{4 \pi }+\frac{1}{8}$$

I have found these *exact* symbolic solutions to be useful when testing the accuracy of multivariate Normal cdf functions (which use numerical integration to solve ... unless they know about the special cases :) )

Apparently, no such simple result is available for higher than 3 dimensions ... but there are tables, and some special results reduced to smaller numbers of integrals ...

Comment: The results for $n\le 5$ are given in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals/3148280#3148280 .

Comment: Proofs can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255368/321264, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/379255/119261.

Comment: Does this result still work if the covariance matrix is singular? The derivation relies on the fact that a density exists.