Gaussian Multivariate Distribution - probability of every coordinate positive?
Let $X\sim\mathrm N(\mu,\Sigma)$ with $\mu\in\mathbb R^d$ and $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ (non-diagonal). Is there an easy way to obtain the probability every coordinate of $X$ is positive?
$$\mathbb P\left(X\ge 0\right)=\mathbb P\left(X_1\ge 0,\ldots,X_d\ge 0\right)$$
As far as I know, this problem typically involves heavy numerical computation for a generic region. However, I hoped there might be a simpler solution for the abovementioned region.

No, you can't. If the solution you seek existed, we could calculate easily all cumulative multivariate normal probabilities (which currently cannot be calculated without numerical methods)

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/379378/321264 and linked posts.

Unfortunately, there couldn't be a simple formula in general, as you can always transfer $X$ to the collection of independent standard normal distributions by setting
$$
Y=\Sigma^{-1/2}(X-\mu)
$$
but this transformation will transfer your orthant $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d: x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d\ge 0\}$ in fairly general ``cone"
$$
A'=\left\{y\in\mathbb{R}^d:\ \sum_{j=1}^d c_{ij} y_j\ge d_i,\ i=1,2,\dots,d\right\}
$$
for some $c,d$.
