# Find $P(X > 0, Y > 0)$, $P(X > 0, Y > X)$ and $P(X > 0, Y > \sqrt{3}X)$ if $(X,Y)$ are i.i.d. standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent standard normal random variables. Find:
>    i) $P(X > 0, Y > 0)$
>   ii) $P(X > 0, Y > X)$
>   iii) $P(X > 0, Y > \sqrt{3}X)$

I am new to this, but I think I have the geometry down. This should involve angles, correct? I interpret this as the relevant volume under the joint density surface as a quadrant-shaped slice of a bell-shaped object. Can someone walk me through the solutions to these?

Comment: Hint (a huge one): $(X,Y)=(R\cos\Theta,R\sin\Theta)$ where $R>0$ almost surely, $(R,\Theta)$ is independent, and $\Theta$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi)$. Apply this.

Comment: do you have a hint for how to apply that to part (i) for example?

Comment: i) is trivial since $\{X>0\}$ and $\{Y>0\}$ are independent, each with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: "do you have a hint for how to apply that" Sure: translate each of the three events involved in terms of $\Theta$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255368/321264