# Calculate $Pr(X \ge 0, Y \ge 0)$ where $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$ and their correlation is 1/2

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, correlation

I've been working on this problem and got stuck.

Assume that X and Y have joint normal distribution, that each $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$, and that their correlation is $\frac{1}{2}$. Calculate $Pr(X \ge 0, Y \ge 0)$.

I know that I can rewrite (X,Y) in terms of independent normal variables (W,T) as follows

$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   X\\
   Y\\
   \end{bmatrix}
=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0\\
   \rho & \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   X\\
   Z\\
   \end{bmatrix}   
$$
where $\rho$ is the correlation. This has left me with
$$
X=X\\
Y=\frac{1}{2}X + Z\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}
$$
And so I have
$$
Pr(X \ge 0, Y \ge 0) = Pr(X \ge 0, \frac{1}{2}X + Z\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \ge 0)
$$
So I just realized that the T variable I had before was superfluous, so I removed it. I am wondering from here if it would make sense to put this:
$$
Pr(X \ge 0, \frac{1}{2}X + Z\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \ge 0)=Pr(X \ge 0, Z\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \ge -\frac{1}{2}X)
$$
Still not sure how to proceed from here. Maybe simplify to
$$
Pr(X \ge 0, \frac{1}{2}X + Z\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \ge 0)=Pr(X \ge 0, 
Z\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \ge 0)
$$
Since we are looking for $Pr(X \ge 0)$ anyway?

Comment: if W is independent of T, you can calculate the joint distribution (because is the product) and parametrize the region

Comment: What would it mean to parametrize the region @vvnitram ? Sorry if that's a dumb question, but I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: Do you know the transformation of random variable formula for the probability density using jacobian?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't @AbishankaSaha

Comment: Already asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255368/getting-px0-y0-for-a-bivariate-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: I can see connection between my question and the one you posted @StubbornAtom and I apologize I did not see that post earlier. However, I am still confused by that alternate proof. Where did that little z come from? How does it go from that integral to h(p)?

Comment: Have a look at the other linked posts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two random variables X and Y are said to have a bivariate normal distribution with parameters $μX, σ2X, μY, σ2Y,$ and $ρ$, if their joint PDF is given by
$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2πσXσY\sqrt{1−ρ2}}e^{−\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}[((x−μ_X)/σ_X)^2+((y−μ_Y)/σ_Y)^2−2ρ(x−μ_X)(y−μ_Y)/σ_Xσ_Y]}$$

$$f_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^\left(-\frac{2}{3}*(x^2+y^2-xy)\right)dy dx$$

$$P(X\gt0,Y\gt0) = \frac{1}{3}$$

evaluated by Wolfram

Comment: So we can just tell it is bivariate normal because they are both normal? Or is joint normal the same as bivariate normal? @SatishRamanathan

Comment: If there happens to be a correlation between otherwise independent X and Y, then the joint distribution is given by the above relationship

Comment: Look at this link it derives what you are asking for.  https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php