# Integral of two error functions times a Gaussian

Tags: probability, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to find some expression for this integral, ideally as a function of the constants. I can't put the full integral in the title as it's too long.

I doubt a closed form exists, but I'm even stuck with how I would go about it.

$$\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_3}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(\mu_3-z)^2}{2\sigma_3}\right)\left(1+\text{Erf}\left[\frac{\mu_2-z}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sigma_2}}\right]\right)\left(1-\text{Erf}\left[\frac{\mu_1-z}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sigma_1}}\right]\right)dz$$

This was derived when considering $P(Y<Z<X)$ where $Y,Z,X$ are random variables that all follow a normal distribution, but with distinct parameters.

Comment: From your integral, tt seems to me that $X,Y,Z$ are independant, doesn't it?

Comment: @NN2 Yes, the assumption is that they're all independent so the joint density is just the product of the marginals

Comment: It is done. I posted the answer on your other question, so maybe you should close this as duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer: If we assume independence, then you have
$$
U := X-Z \sim N(\mu_X-\mu_Z, \sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Z)
$$
and
$$
V := Z-Y \sim N(\mu_Z-\mu_Y, \sigma^2_Z + \sigma^2_Y)
$$
and further,
$$
\text{Cov}(U, V) = -\text{Cov}(Z,Z) = -\sigma^2_Z
$$
so that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
U\\V
\end{bmatrix} \sim N
\left ( 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_X-\mu_Z\\\mu_Z-\mu_Y
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2_X+\sigma_Z^2  & -\sigma^2_Z\\-\sigma^2_Z & \sigma^2_Y+\sigma_Z^2
\end{bmatrix}
\right )
$$
We therefore have
$$
P(Y<Z<X) = P(U > 0, V>0).
$$
If $U,V$ were correlated standard Gaussians with correlation $\rho$, then we would have
$$
P(U>0, V>0) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2\pi} \arcsin \rho
$$
based on the result in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255368/px0-y0-for-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-with-correlation-rho?rq=1). So perhaps you can use the result there to work out something nicer for your problem?