# What is $P(X+Y>0 \mid X>0)$ given that $X,Y$ two different normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

X follows $N(0,\sigma_x^2)$ and Y follows $N(0,\sigma_y^2)$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. What is $P(X+Y>0 \mid X>0)$? If $\sigma_x^2=\sigma_y^2$ we can use symmetry and easily get answer 3/4, but what if $\sigma_x^2 \neq \sigma_y^2$?

Comment: How do you do the case $\sigma_x = \sigma_y$?

Comment: @nejimban Could you please show how to proof it?

Comment: @WilliamM. You can draw a 3-D picture of density function p(X,Y) in a xyz-axis and then the problem is becoming counting the area in xy-plane, since they are symmetry.

Comment: @Hap: I will sketch the idea and let you fill in the gaps.

Comment: Since $(X+Y,X)$ is bivariate normal with mean $(0,0)$, the following result applies: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255368/321264.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X:=-\sigma_XN$ and $Y:=\sigma_YN'$, so $N,N'$ are independent $\mathcal N(0,1)$ variables. Let also $a:=\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}>0$. Then
$$X+Y>0\iff N'>aN.$$
Hence $$\Bbb P(X+Y>0\mid X>0)=\frac{\Bbb P(N'>aN,N<0)}{\Bbb P(N<0)}=1-2\,\Bbb P(N'<aN,N<0).\tag{$\star$}$$

Integrating out $N'$, we are thus reduced to studying the map
$$f(a):=\Bbb P(N'<aN,N<0)=\mathbb E\!\left[\Phi(aN)\,\mathbf 1_{\left\{N<0\right\}}\right]\!,\qquad a>0,$$
where $\Phi$ is the c.d.f. of $\mathcal N(0,1)$, so $\Phi'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\mathrm e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

1. We have $f(1)=\Bbb E\!\left[\Phi(N)\mathbf 1_{\left\{\Phi(N)<\frac12\right\}}\right]=\frac18$, since $\Phi(N)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.
2. An application of the dominated convergence theorem shows that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, with
   $$f'(a)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\Bbb E\!\left[N\mathrm e^{-\frac12a^2N^2}\mathbf 1_{\{N<0\}}\right]=\frac1{2\pi}\left[-\frac1{(1+a^2)}\mathrm e^{-\frac12(1+a^2)x^2}\right]_{x\to-\infty}^{x=0}=-\frac1{2(1+a^2)\pi}.$$

From 1. and 2., we deduce that
$$f(a)=f(1)+\int_1^af'(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(1)-\frac1{2\pi}\Bigl[\arctan t\Bigr]_{t=1}^{t=a}=\frac14-\frac1{2\pi}\arctan a.$$

Recalling $(\star)$ and the value of $a$, we conclude that
$$\mathbb P(X+Y>0\mid X>0)=\frac12+\frac1{\pi}\,\arctan\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}.$$

Comment: Thanks, it's really clear

Comment: Hi nejimban. This is a nice technique! But I agree with Jingxu's answer below that we'd expect the probability to vary from $ 1$ to $\tfrac 12$ as $\sigma_Y$ varies from $0$ to $\infty$. It looks to me like an extra factor of $\tfrac 12$ has appeared in the calculation of $f'(a)$ - I get $f'(a) = -\frac 1{2 \pi(a^2 + 1)}$, and I think after that the two answers agree.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You are completely right and I am ashamed that this mistake has remained for so long. Thank you!