# What is $P(X+Y>0 \mid X<0)$ given $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, $Y\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, $Corr(X,Y)=\rho>0$?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve the problem indicated in the title. I found a similar one in this link,
[What is $P(X+Y>0 \mid X>0)$ given that $X,Y$ two different normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433691/what-is-pxy0-mid-x0-given-that-x-y-two-different-normal)

My problem differs from the linked one as $X$ and $Y$ are correlated in my problem. But I un unclear about from which step should the solution to my problem differs from the linked one. I guess $\rho$ should show up in the last step. Could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

(1) the joint density function of $X,Y$ is given as
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)= \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)}(x^2-2\rho xy+y^2)\right)}$$

(2) by the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$P(X+Y>0|X<0)=\frac{P(X+Y>0,X<0)}{P(X<0)}$$ The denominator is $\frac12$ by symmetry, the numerator can be evaluated as a double integral on the set $\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x+y>0,x<0\right\}$.

Comment: How do you know $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal?

Comment: Do you mean to evaluate the double integral $$\int_{-x}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{0} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \;\mathrm{dx}{dy}$$, assuming $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal?

Comment: @kimchi lover maybe the answer at the following link is more rigorous. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255368/px0-y0-for-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-with-correlation-rho

Comment: @che00c it should be $$\int_0^{\infty} \int_{-y}^0f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we take $\sigma^2=1.$ Write $Y=\rho X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is independent of $X$. Denoting $\cos \theta=\sqrt{\frac{1+\rho}{2}}$ and $\sin \theta=\sqrt{\frac{1-\rho}{2}}$ with $0<\theta<\pi/2$ we can write
$$\Pr(X+Y>0|X<0)=\Pr(X\cos \theta+Z\sin \theta>0|X<0)=\frac{\theta}{\pi}.$$