# Matrix operation - half inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand the inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\,\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$$

But what is the operation, $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^{-1/2}$?

Comment: Given $A$, you could write $B = A^{-1/2}$ if $B^2 = A^{-1}$. This may or may not exist, and may or may not be unique (hence an issue with the notation....).

Comment: What would be the operations involved? I'm trying to figure out [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1757343/152225).

Comment: Wikipedia has [a formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix).

Comment: So we are taking the square root of the inverse. So first we calculate the inverse, and then we use the horrifying formula in the Wikipedia link, is that correct?

Comment: Or the other way around, whichever seems less painful.

Comment: The question you are referring to concerns symmetric, positive definite matrices. In this case, there is a unique solution $B$ to the equation $B^2=A^{-1}$ if one in addition assumes that $B$ is symmetric and positive definite. This can be obtained by diagonalizing,  taking one over the square roots of the eigenvalues and then undo the diagonalization.