# Projection theorem for conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, covariance, variance

$\def\cov{\mathop{\mathrm{cov}}}\def\var{\mathop{\mathrm{var}}}$My professor uses something that he calls the "projection theorem", to get rid of the condition in conditional probabilities (expectation and variance). I have not found anything about it on the internet, so I am wondering where it comes from, and if it is right.

Here is the so-called "projection theorem":

$$E[\tilde{x}\mid \tilde{y} = y] = E[\tilde{x}] + \frac{\cov(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})}{\var(\tilde{y})}\times(\tilde{y}-E(\tilde{y})),$$

and

$$\var[\tilde{x}\mid \tilde{y}] = \var(\tilde{x})-\frac{\cov^2(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})}{\var(\tilde{y})}.$$

Are these formulas correct?

Comment: They are correct if $\tilde x$ and $\tilde y$ have a joint normal distribution.

Comment: @JohnDawkins thank you. Forgive my ignorance, but what does joint probability mean? And do you have any reference (like any online course/wikipedia) where I can find these? Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution and then google "bivariate nprmal distribution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your professor used them in a finance class because the first time I heard (I tried to google) the term "projection theorem" was in my asset pricing class. As John said, they are correct if $x$ and $y$ are jointly normal.

For any two joint normal random variables distributed as

$$ (X,Y) \sim N \Big(\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_X \\
\mu_Y
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_X^2 & \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y \\
  \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y & \sigma_Y^2
\end{bmatrix} \Big)$$
, we have
\begin{align}
E(Y|X=x)= \mu_Y+\frac{\rho \sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X),
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
Var(Y|X=x) &= E(Y^2|X=x)-[E(Y|X=x)]^2 =(1-\rho^2)\sigma_Y^2.
\end{align}
You can verify that equations above are consistent with the theorem.

Comment: A very good derivation is there: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36544/297803