# Conditional expectation of uniformly distributed variable

Tags: conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

I am given two independently distributed variables, X and Y. Both are uniform on the interval (-1,1).

What is $\mathrm{E}(X|Z)$ when $Z=\alpha + \beta X + Y$? I am a bit clueless on how to approach the problem. Is there something similar to the projection theorem ([Projection theorem for conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726525/projection-theorem-for-conditional-probability)) for Uniform Distributions?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $W=Z-\alpha=\beta X+Y$. Since $\alpha$ is a constant,
$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Z\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid W\right]$.

1. Compute the CDF of $X$ and $W$:
   $$
   F_{X,W}(x,w)
   =\mathbb{P}(X\leq x,W\leq w)
   $$
2. Compute the joint PDF of $X$ and $W$ by taking derivatives:
   $$
   f_{X,W}
   =\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x\partial w}\left[F_{X,W}\right]
   $$
3. Compute the density of $X$ conditional on $W$:
   $$
   f_{X\mid W}(x\mid w)=\frac{f_{X,W}(x,w)}{f_{X}(x)}
   $$
4. Use the conditional density to resolve the expectation:
   $$
   \mathbb{E}\left[X\mid W\right]
   =\int x f_{X\mid W}(x\mid w)dx
   $$

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Indeed, I "knew" the general procedure, but seem to be struggling with setting up the joint CDF, as $W$ and $X$ are not independent.

Comment: @max1993: $$\mathbb{P}(X\leq x,W\leq w)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x,Y\leq w-\beta X)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\left[f_{X}(t)\int_{-\infty}^{w-\beta t}f_{Y}(s)ds\right]dt$$

Answer (score 0):

For all interested, I think the answer is along the following lines:

Suppose $X \sim U[0,1],Y \sim U[0,k], k \geq 1$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z=X+Y$.
Then, we have:
$$f_z(z) = \int_{\Omega(z)}f_x(u)f_y(z-u)$$
Depending on $z$, we have three different intervals over which to integrate:
$$
f_z(z)= \begin{cases}
 \int_0^z \frac{1}{k}du = \frac{z}{k}, & \text{for } 0\leq z\leq 1\\
 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{k}du = \frac{1}{k}, & \text{for } 1\leq z\leq k\\
 \int_{z-k}^1 \frac{1}{k}du = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{z-k}{k} , & \text{for } k\leq z\leq k+1
\end{cases}
$$

The conditional pdf of $X$ given $Z$ is then given by: 
$$
f_{x|z}(x|z) = \frac{f_{z|x}(z|x) f_x(x)}{f_z(z)}
$$

Thus, for the three intervals of $z$ we have:

$$
f_{x|z}(x|z)= \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{z}, & \text{for } 0\leq z\leq 1 \text{ and } 0\leq x \leq z\\
 1, & \text{for } 1\leq z\leq k \text{ and } 0\leq x \leq 1\\
 \frac{1}{k+1-z}, & \text{for } k\leq z\leq k+1 \text{ and } z-k\leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

The expected value $\mathbb{E}[X|Z]$ follows immediately and is given by

$$
\mathbb{E}(x|z)= \begin{cases}
 \frac{\hat{z}}{2}, & \text{for } 0\leq z\leq 1\\
 \frac{1}{2}, & \text{for } 1\leq z\leq k\\
 \frac{1}{2} (1-k+\hat{z}), & \text{for } k\leq z\leq k+1
\end{cases}
$$

The extension for the general case follows if $X = a+(b-a) \hat{X}$, $Y = c+(b-a) \hat{Y}$, whereby the variables with a hat are the ones that I used previously.