# Bivariate normal distribution , link $\Bbb E(Y\mid X=x)$ and $\Bbb E(X\mid Y=y)$

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, bivariate-distributions

I read in the answers to this question ([Bivariate Normal Conditional Variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33993/bivariate-normal-conditional-variance)) that

$$\Bbb E(Y\mid{X=x})=\mu_Y + \rho \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)$$

By symmetry I would say that

$$\Bbb E(X\mid{Y=y})=\mu_X + \rho \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(y-\mu_Y)$$

Is this correct ?

> Next question, referring to the picture below, does taking
>   expectations along the red lines (conditionning on X) or along the
>   blue lines (conditioning on Y) yield the same line in this picture ?

[image]

I can see that these equations are different, but that is because they are in another basis, do these equations represent the same line ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct ?

Yes.  Symmetry is applicable.

There is not much else to say.

Comment: Are both lines the principal axis of the ellipses?

Comment: see the picture that I added